# How to change from "example.com" to "mail.exmaple.com" for mail server?

Tags: cpanel, exim

The MTA that running on my server is ( Exim ) and I need to specify if the current mail server is ( example.com ) or ( mail.example.com ), and if it's ( example.com ) I need to change it to ( mail.example.com )

So how can I make a check then a change if it was needed ?

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to edit your domain DNS zone, Check your MX record entry and update it which you want

Comment: I already did that, created a MX record and pointed 'example.com' to 'mail.example.com' to make sure 'mail.example.com' is the only server that responsible for my website incoming/outcoming emails, but how to make sure it's already so now ?